# Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Sys._Application' cannot be converted to type 'Sys._Application'.Parameter name: instance

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the error;
MVC Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Sys._Application' cannot be converted to type 'Sys._Application'.Parameter name: instance

I am getting this error in my MVC application and I am wondering if it is to do with the upgrade to ie8? I do not get the problem in FF.
The debugger locates the error in the MicrosoftAjax.debug.js file when I am doing a post.

Because I am working in MVC, the usual solution; set ScriptMode to Release does not apply.

Answer (score 11):

This might be what you were looking for. I've spent this entire afternoon trying to find a solution and every other article I read suggested either setting ScriptMode to Release in the `asp:ScriptManager` or disabling `SmartNavigation`. [This article](http://sympmarc.com/2010/08/28/how-to-fix-sys-argumenttypeexception-object-of-type-sys-_application-cannot-be-converted-to-type-sys-_application-error/) suggests changing the following line in your `web.config` to false:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

That worked for me, with any luck it will work for you too.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting an exception in `ScriptResource.axd`:

```
Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Object' cannot be converted to type 'Array'.
```

Changing `ScriptMode` to `Release` fixed the issue.